# A frameless window in QML is not updated automatically

Tags: c++, qt, qml

If the window to set the flag Qt.FramelessWindowHint it stops updating automatically.
Video https://youtu.be/9LJyJWr1m9M
Please help solve the problem.

**UPD:**
My system: linux x64
The project for the sample http://rghost.ru/69VBkk2sr In the project, you can uncomment the line with Qt.FramelessWindowHint and color of the screen may be changed by pressing.

Example code:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    // Try comment and uncomment next line
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    width: 640
    height: 480
    color: marea.pressed ? "lightblue" : "orange"
    MouseArea {
        id: marea
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems the problem is on your side (I mean it can be your hardware or OS). For me screen changes color no matter if the `Qt.FramelessWindowHint` `flag` is enabled or not.

Comment: @FilipHazubski thanks for your answer. Your OS is Windows?